# Getting your free RHN Entitlements for Para-Virtualised machines?

Tags: virtualization, xen, redhat, rhel5

We run Xen on an RHEL 5 host with RHEL 5 paravirtualised guests.

In theory we are entitled to 4 free entitlemets for paravirtualised guests on each Xen host with the "Virtualisation" entitlement.

I have been banging my head off this for days now - and I just can't get the PV guests to connect to RHN without consuming a regular entitlement. Since we have 6 PV hosts, we're talking about needing to pay for up to 24 extra and un-needed entitlements - a LOT of money!

If anyone has managed to get this to work as it should, any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Bart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review http://kbase.redhat.com/faq/docs/DOC-9933 and try the suggestions given there.